# Why were the ways of the Force considered a "religion" in the Galaxy Far Far Away during ANH by non-Force-users?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, religion, sith

For some reason, the ways of the Force are nearly universally considered a ***religion*** in the Galaxy Far Far Away during year 0 BBY by "laymen" (e.g. non-Jedi-nor-Sith):

> **Han Solo:** Hokey ***religions*** and ancient weapons are no match for a good blaster at your side, kid.

> **Motti:** Your sad devotion to that ancient ***religion*** has not helped you conjure up the stolen data tapes or given you clairvoyance enough to find the Rebels' hidden fort- [grasps his throat as if he is being choked]

> **Tarkin:** The Jedi are extinct. Their fire has gone out of the universe. You, my friend, are all that's left of their ***religion***.

**Why exactly was it considered "religion"?** (by people who were not Jedi or Sith who had no idea about the spiritual components of it).

There was no deity nor worship which usually define religion. **As a matter of fact, aside from the Jedi and the Sith internal beliefs themselves, there was no spiritual angle at all** (this is an important point. Yoda may have known about spirituality and life after death thing. But Han Solo couldn't have known, neither did Motti).

The way I see it, to the rest of the galaxy, the ways of the Force were more akin to magic as practiced by Uri Geller or Houdini - a somewhat supernatural-seeming set of tricks with no spiritual component. Nobody ever referred to such people/movements as "religions" in real life.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/20467/4495

Comment: @MrLister - Not really, sorry. This question is about why it was considered a religion, NOT why it changed from being  "real" to "religion" in the intervening period.

Comment: It wasn't a *religion*, it was *science*! It's got Midichlorian counters and everything!

Comment: @Wikis - Jeff Atwood must have loved the Jedi then :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The entire galaxy seems to have suffered an immense bout of amnesia about the Jedi - people who could have and should have known Jedi act as if they have no knowledge of them at all.

All that most people know of them, especially people who never saw or interacted of them before the Empire rose, is what they've heard.

The Jedi were an exclusive order, known for being wise.  They could preform miracles, and professed a faith and belief in something that the average person could not see or feel.

They promised a form of everlasting life after death (becoming 'one with the Force'), lived in a massive Temple, and the meaning and reasons for much that they did was non-obvious to most people.

In short, the Jedi were all followers of the same religion.  The Sith were followers of a different version of this religion.  The only difference between their religion and the religions we have today are that the Jedi and Sith can use their belief to preform repeatable, measurable actions.

Give it a generation for the rest of what they said and did to fade into the mists of time (you can bet the Emperor didn't let much in the way of official records remain) and 'religion' becomes a very apt description of them.

Comment: +1 Good points.  I would note:  There were not infinite numbers of Jedi.  Most people of the galaxy probably lived their entire lives never meeting, let alone even seeing a Jedi or Sith, even before the purge.  And for these beings and their supposed "powers" and belief in something no one else felt or knew, it would easily be viewed as a religion.  As for repeatable actions, there are many of faiths in the world today, who would say that they can create these repeatable, measurable actions as part of their faith.  It's part of their religion and faith.  The Jedi/Sith are no different.

Comment: "They promised a form of everlasting life after death (becoming 'one with the Force')" - did they promise that to non-Jedi?

Comment: @DVK - no, but most religions only promise a form of an afterlife to *members of their religion* - precisely what the Jedi did.

Comment: @SSumner - sorry, to be clearer - they never TOLD the non-Jedi about Force Ghosts and Force-become-one. My point is not whether Jedi could have been considered a religion from THEIR point of view, but from the point of view of NON-Jedi.

Comment: @DVK, but the point is you have rumors of Jedi powers and such, and you have an entire galaxy where the vast majority of the population has never met them or interacted with them. Once they all get wiped out, it seems less laser-guided amnesia and just cynicism and a general lack of information.

Comment: @DVK - I see where you're coming from, but from the general comments made by Jedi on missions about the Force, and the prevalent greeting of "May the Force be with you" does indicate a somewhat reclusive religion with the knights as "missionaries" that don't spread their "gospel" by word, but by action - not unlike some monastic orders

Answer (score 3):

### Because they *were* a religion

To begin with, the Jedi and the Sith believe in a supernatural *force* that underlies everything. What’s more, the Jedi, at least, believe that the Force has a will (and they’re almost certainly right), meaning that they see it as conscious in some broad sense. An omnipresent consciousness that, at least broadly, directs everything, and to which its followers devote their lives? That certainly sounds like a religion to me.

Listen to how Obi-Wan talks about it:

> “**The Force works in mysterious ways**, but it leads us to where we need
> to be in order to achieve balance. Many Sith believe that the dark
> side holds more power, but that is simply not true.”
>
> Han strained his ears to catch what the old man said next.
>
> “**It was the Force that brought me into your life, and it is the Force
> that will guide you to your destiny**.”
>
> <sub>*The Princess, the Scoundrel, and the Farm Boy*</sub>

The Sith may see the Force very differently, but they too believe that it has a sort of consciousness, that it guides their lives.  Vader does:

> It was his duty to rule them all. He saw that now. **It was the manifest
> will of the Force.** Existence without proper rule was chaos, disorder,
> suboptimal. The Force—invisible but ubiquitous—bent toward order and
> was the tool through which order could and must be imposed, but not
> through harmony, not through peaceful coexistence. That had been the
> approach of the Jedi, a foolish, failed approach that only fomented
> more disorder. Vader and his Master imposed order the only way it
> could be imposed, **the way the Force required that it be imposed**,
> through conquest, by forcing the disorder to submit to the order, by
> bending the weak to the will of the strong.
>
> <sub>*Lords of the Sith*</sub>

Even Sidious does:

> Vader knew the reply. “There are no coincidences, Master.”
>
> “And that, my apprentice, is why Murkhana matters to us. Because **the
> dark side of the Force has for whatever reason brought that world to
> our attention** once more—as you should well understand.”
>
> <sub>*Tarkin*</sub>

There’s another crucial point, though. The Jedi and the Sith followed the ways of the Force, but they were not the only ones. Many, many other sentient beings followed the ways of the Force *purely* as a religion, without ever using—or, indeed, being capable of using—the Force in an active sense.

For example, the Church of the Force was an organization of laypeople who follow the ways of the Force. Some among the Lasat believed in the Force, which they called the Ashla. The most detailed description comes from the novelization of *Rogue One*, which shows that many different faiths are based around the Force, and see it in many different ways:

> What is the Force of Others? To ask this, you must ask one question
> and a thousand.
>
> To a cultist of the Huiyui-Tni, you must ask, “What is the exhalation
> of the true, amphibious god?” To a Jedi, you must ask, “What is it
> that binds and defines all life?” To a child of the Esoteric Pulsar,
> you must ask, “Show me the secret pages of the Book of Stars.” To a
> faithless man, you must ask, “What power enables prophecy and sorcery
> in a world controlled by logic and law?”
>
> <sub>*Rogue One: A Star Wars Story*</sub>

Indeed, it seems likely that the Force is better-known in many places as a religion: as something that, say, the Church of the Force believes in, than as “that thing that the Jedi use to do crazy things.” There are only 10,000 Jedi, after all, and who knows how many billions or trillions of adherents of the Church of the Force, the Huiyui-Tni, the Lasat Ashla, and so forth.

With all this context in mind, then, it would be accurate, natural, and indeed automatic to refer to the ways of the Force as a religion, and to conceive of the Jedi as religious.

Answer (score 2):

The in-universe answer is that this "amnesia" effect was intentional - it's partly caused by the Dark Side clouding the galaxy, but also by twenty years of propaganda by the Galactic Empire. Attitudes can change a lot in twenty years, especially when someone is practically brain-washing the public. It's somewhat alluded to in a few sources, but I don't have any specifics at the moment.

The actual answer, from a production standpoint, is that originally (before the prequels), George Lucas had intended much more time to have passed between the fall of the Jedi and the original movie. The dialogue was written such that it had been almost 30-40 years, with younger people like Han Solo never having known anything other than the Empire. In that version, it was understood that Vader's turn to the Dark Side was much more gradual, and that Obi-Wan had taken it upon himself to train an adult Anakin almost his own age. It was also implied that Luke & Leia's mom had stuck with Vader several years into the Empire stage of things, than later fled to Alderaan once she learned she was pregnant, dying a few years later.

Obviously, the prequels changed a LOT of the backstory understood or assumed at the time. A lot of fans under 30 don't really understand that, since the entire continuity was basically retconned in 1999.

A more recent "post-Prequels" answer would be that the Jedi are a religion in that they have a set of rules to live by, a central figure to "worship" (The Force), and a certain exclusivity that spans race or creed.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it IS a religion, as even some martial arts like gung-fu were once considered a religion, because a religion is all about self improvement on all levels which is what real gung-fu is also all about.

Jedi is really a parralel to Christianity, since the Jedi were essentially Christians and God's prophets, but who were also martial arts masters, which is why the elements taken from the Shaolin monks and Samurai or also in there as well.

Jedi are monk warriors which is exactly what Shaolin monks were called and known as. Numerous elements from Star Wars were taken from the bible, including the name Jedi itself which comes from the name Jedidiah, which is the name the GOD gave to Solomon. So the word Jedi IS actually from God Himself.

The Shaolin monks practiced Buddhism and some of the very philosophies of the Jedi are taken from the Shaolin and Buddhist teachings, mostly some of the general meditative techniques along with some philosophy.

So hopefully you can see that from these parralels, that the Jedi is very much a real religion that had nearly gone extinct since you could only be a Jedi by having said abilities and training. There was tens of thousands of Jedi throughout the galaxy at one point, but in something the size of a galaxy, that's not many at all.

Comment: "the Jedi were essentially Christians and God's prophets" ... not to rain on your parade, but how exactly do you figure that? Or what do you mean by it?

Comment: Because it's the bible, it's the prophets empowered by God's Spirit (The force/power) as Jesus even called it the latter 3 times, that gives the prophets their power, protection, knowledge, etc. Many of the prophets such as Elija and Elisha did fight against the prophets of Baal, akin to the Sith. 

God's prophets were teachers or morality and spirituality just as Jedi are, and of course their religion was what God taught Moses and Israel. The Jedi are more warrior-centric where is where the martial arts, Shaolin and Samurai aspects comes into play, melding the two into what Lucas created.

Comment: Do you have some support of direct inspiration / intentional parallels from George Lucas himself, or only your own speculations? This being SE and not a forum, the former is encouraged and the latter is discouraged. I will also point out that the Jedi are nowhere shown to be leaders of the general population as the Biblical Judges were, for example. So I question your parallel. The mere existence of vague similarities based on your own speculation doesn't establish that the Jedi are "essentially Christians," whether in-universe or out-of-universe.

Comment: The biblical parallels are numerous. Some brief examples are the lightsaber in Genesis 3:24 where we're told "God places the cherubim and the Flaming Sword which turned every way to guard the way to the tree of life". A flame emits light, and a sword is also a saber, flaming sword = light saber. Anakins name was taken from the Anakims, a race of giants the the Israelites encountered. The second death Star (dark side) was orbiting the forest moon of Endor. King Saul went to consult a witch, the dark side, at En-Dor. Obi-wan aka Prophet Obi-Diah.. Cont'd

Comment: In the beginning of Star Wars we read "Long, long ago, in a galaxy far, far away (there broke out) Star Wars. Both the bible and ancient records from numerous civilizations reveal that there were ancient wars "among the gods" throughout the universe. In the bible, Angels = Stars, and we know that Satan and his angels (stars) fought Michael and his angels (Stars), so long, long ago and far, far away throughout the universe, the bible shows that there were in fact "Star Wars" that occurred. Revelation 1:20 "The mystery of the seven stars..The seven stars are the angels of the seven churches,"

Comment: I'm not only paralelling the Jedi with the judges, but mainly with prophets as mentioned, which were spiritual leaders/teachers of the people, as Jedi also were. This is something that Luke also found out years after ROTJ as there was a spiritual/moral dimension to being a Jedi that his training skipped because they were more concerned with teaching him to become a weapon to defeat Vader and Palpatine at the time. Jedi had in fact always been the spiritual teachers as "guardians and peace and justice" in the old republic before and then after the Empire was defeated.

Comment: I agree with some of your similarities (though not all of them), but you're failing to establish how this makes the Jedi "essentially Christians and God's prophets." We know that GL likes to include what he calls "mythological motifs" and elements of various religions, but has he anywhere stated that the Jedi were "essentially Christians and God's prophets" (or something of the kind)? Vague similarities do not establish your point. Otherwise, edit your answer to say that "some similarities exist to Christian monastic / Crusading orders," or something like that.

Comment: The name Jedi itself is not of human orgins, but is the name the GOD Himself gave to Solomon through the prophet Samuel (2 Samuel 12:25). Obi Wan said that the Jedi were the guardians of peace for 1000 generations. God also said that He will show mercy to the 1000th generation of those that love Him and keep His commandments, just as Jedi are told to obey the light side (keep God's commandments, thus the light side (God) showed them mercy to the 1000th generation, after which the dark side took over briefly. Lucas also said in a TV interview in the early 80's he got a lot of it from the bible.

Comment: Lucas also said that he leaves some things up to the people to decide, as the case with whether or not Palpatine threw the fight with Mace Windu or if Mace did in fact defeat Palpatine legitimately. There are so many parallels that I'm working on a book and have four chapters already. Almost the entire scene where Yoda levitates Lukes X-wing out of the Dagobah Swamp is lifted from the pages of the bible, with the dialogue "I don't believe it... that is why you fail" paraphrased from Christ Himself. Lucas also mentioned that he drew from mythology, The Shaolin monks and Japanese Samurai.

Comment: Of course he got a lot of it from the Bible or Christian history, obviously. Of course there are parallels. The quasi-virgin birth, the monastic order sworn to poverty (also parallels with Eastern orders), the name Anakin = Anakim (which is the plural form, by the way, not "Anakims"), etc. ***However, the existence of parallels does not establish your fanfic as canon.*** BTW, the name Jedi is not "from God," it's probably from Japanese ( http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105652/what-is-the-origin-of-the-name-jedi ).

Comment: Tarkin himself told Vader "The Jedi are extinct, their fire has gone out of the universe, you my friend are all that's left of their religion" and General Tagge said "Your sad devotion to the ancient religion doesn't not help you conjure up the stolen data tapes..." Just as Christianity and God's ways given to Israel thousands of years prior are also ancient religions. 

Jesus directly called the Father "the power" Matthew 26:64 "..hereafter you will see the Son of Man sitting at the right hand of the Power, and coming on the clouds of heaven.” Power and force are certainly synonymous.

Comment: Some of your parallels are compelling, others are nonsense, but none of it establishes a ***canonical*** link between the Jedi and real-world religious orders. You can speculate on your own time, but you are not answering the question.

Comment: I never said it was cannon.. it's called using insight, wisdom and true vision to understand that it parallels our world. Just as the fall of the republic is really about the fall of the United States, which IS a republic, not a "democracy" as so many are deceived about. The Empire is the old Roman Empire which is why as Tarkin said "The regional governors now have direct control over their territories".. this is take directly from the governmental structure of the Roman Empire of which Herod was one of the regional governors over Judea at that time, showing the same set up.

Comment: Even the secular media saw the parallels between the fall of the republic and what was going on with the US at the time, which Akakins line "If you're not with me, then you're my enemy", linking it to what Bush said in his terrorist speech of "if you're not with us, then you're with the terrorists", but Lucas said he wrote that 30 years before because he already understood that the US was taken over after the Civil War once it became a corporation. Just Saturns moon Mimas is the model for the death star http://www.space.com/10887-saturn-moon-mimas-photos-death-star.html

Comment: The bible shows that the Empire of Revelation will only last a "short time", just as the Empire in Star Wars only lasted 20 years, while the republic lasted for 25,000 years, something that shocked those in the remnants of the empire. The bible shows that two of God's prophets will square off against two dark side agents, the Beast and the false prophet, the former who will be the Emperor of the resurrected "holy" roman empire in the end times. Just as Yoda and Obi-Wan squared off against the Emperor and Vader.. the parallels go on and on..

Comment: Your speculations **still aren't canon** and **aren't reasonably supported by any evidence.** Maybe it makes sense to you, but it's still essentially fanfiction. Unless you can link a parallel ***directly*** to something that GL has said or to some other source of canonical evidence, your parallels are essentially meaningless for the purposes of the question that you're purporting to answer. Even in that case, the applicability of your answer is questionable since OP is clearly asking for a preferably **in-universe** explanation.

Comment: Even many of the examples in the latter books of how the dark side operates and tricks people are what James, Peter and Paul said regarding sin and how it sneaks up on us, makes lofty promises and delivers only short pleasure for long term pain and death, the quick and easy path as all Jedi teachers so constant warn their students about. The point is in almost every area of Star Wars there are almost direct biblical parallels, and some lifted right out of those pages, more than enough to establish a powerful direct link between the two. Those that don't see it usually don't want to. Peace.

Comment: I don't care about whether you can justify your parallels in your own mind, I care about whether they are ***canonical and relevant.*** If you can't link them directly to a canonical source of information, you can't improve your answer.

Comment: Watch Star Wars itself as I quoted Tarkin and General Tagge both said that it WAS a RELIGION.. can't get anymore "In universe" than that. 
General Tagge "Ancient relgion"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zzs-OvfG8tE

Furthermore, the question did not stipulate "in universe" only as it even mentioned people in THIS world as part of the confusion (Houdini/Uri Geller). I've mentioned the direct and synonymous biblical, historical, mystical, prophetic and other links directly ANSWERING the question as to WHY it was considered a religion as the force IS the Diety (God) at the heart of the lightside

Comment: Just as in the latter books, Luke eventually found out that a dark side woman named Abeloth was the literal personification of the Dark Side of the force, akin to Satan in the bible this giving it a deity to focus on making it a religion, just as the poster made the original quotes from Han, Tarkin and Tagge. My answers gave numerous instances supporting the idea from this world and Star Wars that it is a religion.
A religion doesn't always need a deity anyway, as Buddhism, Qui-gong and even gung-fu were considered religions for millennia. The original movies are as CANON as you can get.

Comment: The Tarkin quote is part of the question. You are not providing any evidence for why the Jedi system of conduct is considered a religion by the people in the movies, either in-universe or out-of-universe. Your answer doesn't even mention George Lucas or any other source of canon information, let alone provide any link (as in: hyperlink, as in on the internet) to where they have said anything to support your specific parallels as being intended in the way that you have interpreted them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30901/discussion-between-wolfie-inu-and-jediwitness).

Answer (score 0):

The Force is a real thing in the series, yes, but its existence brings about many questions. Why can some people use it, others only feel it, and others seemingly not interact with it at all? what are the implications of the existence of such a thing? What should a person be cautious about with respect to it, and what should they embrace? What are the best ways to use it?

In the Expanded Universe, the very first Force-users didn't even refer to the Light Side and the Dark Side as such: those names came later, as part of their attempts to answer these questions. These attempts moved the Force-using orders out of science and into philosophy, but they didn't stop there. They developed their own traditions and rituals, taking on the trappings of religion as they developed these ways to transmit the knowledge and disciplines they had developed. Eventually they became indistinguishable from religions, and so the people began to think of them as such.

Comment: As I've mentioned a few times on this site and in many comments above, the answers to many of these questions are found in the bible as there are many direct and other strong parallels between the two, though some refuse to see it. Just as God (the power, force, light side) chooses people that have the necessary character and potential to complete the training and be used for His will, the force does the same thing. The "living force" is the "living waters" of God's Holy Spirit that guides a willing person aka Jedi to obeying the will of the force. Just as God does with true Christians

Comment: However, if you are looking a Star Wars only answer to this question, then I have never come across one in the over 100 books, source books, role playing material, forums, etc. But the bible and other secular knowledge does answer these questions, but some people hate to bring any worldly religion into this discussion, to each his own.

Answer (score 0):

This practice of the monastic Jedi is often referred to as a religion by the uninitiated. I can think of another practice often referred to a religion with no beliefs about the spirit, not yearning to be with any god; Zen Buddhism.

The Zen masters were said to have near magic-like powers, like the ability to predict when they would pass on. (See The Koan "Last Poem of Hoshin") Some Zen masters were said to be unbeatably strong simply be realizing the truth of Zen. See The Koan "Great Waves".)

The practitioners do not believe in any god, even Buddha, the source of much of their teachings is seen as a hindrance to enlightenment. “If you meet the Buddha, kill him.”– Linji

So too are the ways of the Jedi. To the uninitiated, both appear as magic as in Arthur C Clarke's 3rd Law "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic."

So both appear to be religions. Neither are. But if you are some moisture farmer on the far end of the galaxy, how would you ever know?

Comment: Hey man, this is a great first post! It might be helpful if you could provide some links to what you are quoting, like the Last Poem of Hoshin for instance. I am also not exactly sure that Clarke's 3rd law applies here, as Zen masters aren't really known by their usage of advanced technology

Comment: You are right on here. Completely valid.