# According to Disney is Jediism a religion?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, disney

Now according to ["A New Hope"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22830/why-were-the-ways-of-the-force-considered-a-religion-in-the-galaxy-far-far-awa?rq=1) Jediism is considered a religion.

Now according to "The Last Jedi" Luke says the following(Thanks Valorum).

> The Sacred Jedi texts!

Then Yoda says.

> ... that library contained nothing that the girl Rey does not already possess

He goes to burn the Jedi temple. So I believe there are 2 ways to interpret this statement.

1. Jediism is a religion but Rey has discovered the truths herself.
2. Yoda is implying that it isn't in fact a religion.

Is there maybe a way from scripts or something to determine which he is implying?

Comment: I feel like there's only one way to interpret that statement.

Comment: @Adamant Which is? I have talked to film majors(not that they are experts) and gotten different answers.

Comment: Pretty much that Jedism is a religion.

Comment: That's not what Yoda says. He says *"...that library contained nothing that the girl Rey does not already possess"*. Nothing about religion

Comment: @Valorum Then Luke said something about religion.   I do admit it was a long time ago since I have see the movie.

Comment: Luke says "*The Sacred Jedi texts!*". Sacred implies religion.

Comment: Note that Yoda burns the Jedi temple, but not the books (there's a later brief shot of them on the Falcon). So when he says the temple contains "nothing that the girl Rey does not already possess," he's basically trolling Luke (and by extension the audience).

Comment: @Valorum Almost certain the line is "The sacred texts!" The copious number of memes with that version of the line may serve as backup.

Comment: Anything from "A New Hope" is also Disney canon, so yes.

Comment: @NKCampbell the prequel are disney cannon and frankly George Lucas said making/during them that making Jedism a religion was a mistake which is why they view Jedism well differently in the prequels.

Comment: @William Of course there's multiple complex answers here, like the idea of the Jedi not viewing themselves as a religion in their height, but later on other groups forming religions based around the Jedi from the old legends of the force floating around

Comment: @Sydney that is not what George Lucas implied in his talks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to an archaeologist who interviewed Luke, the Jedi were indeed a religious order.

> *I took copious notes and drew sketches. Luke and I discussed my
> biological theories and speculations about all the mini-ecosystems we
> encountered along the way. We also talked about the luminous writing
> and drawings, and **Luke explained to me that he thought they were
> related to the Jedi religion.** The gathering of knowledge in the face
> of our certain doom kept us sane and gave us the drive to go on, step
> after step, fight after fight.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Legends of Luke Skywalker](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Legends_of_Luke_Skywalker)</sup></sub>

Comment: I do not understand you link.  Is this from one of the books.  Also I'm assuming this post Disney owned them.

Comment: @William - Yes, this book was released as part of the new [Journey to Star Wars: The Last Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Journey_to_Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi) book series and is considered to be fully canon.