# Are there other religions in the Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars

According to [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/179997/according-to-disney-is-jediism-a-religion?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C144.9688) Jediism is a religion.

So my question is - Are there other religions in the Star Wars Universe?

Comment: There are trillions of people in the Star Wars universe. So, yes. Lots of religions; https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Religions

Comment: Also potentially: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9661/do-heaven-and-hell-exist-in-star-wars

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are countless religions across the *Star Wars* galaxy. Many considered Jedha holy, such as [The Church of the Force](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Church_of_the_Force), [Ninn Orthodoxy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ninn_Orthodoxy), [Guardians of the Whills](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Whills), [Central Isopter](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Central_Isopter), and [Phirmism](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Phirmism).

[image]

Other Force groups such as the [Sith](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sith) and [Nightsisters](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Nightsisters?so=search) also had their own religious beliefs.

Trandoshans worshipped a goddess called the [Scorekeeper](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Scorekeeper).

[Mandalorians](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mandalorian) had various religious beliefs.

> Weapons are a part of my religion. - Din Djarin

They were not united, with some Mandalorians considering [The Children of the Watch](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Children_of_the_Watch) to be a "cult of religious zealots."

The Ewoks mistook C-3P0 for a god.

[image]

Comment: You've missed more than a hundred; https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Religions

Comment: @Valorum Many of those are from Legends, but yes, this answer is not a complete list.

Comment: List is not required, i just wanted to know about some of them and if they even existed

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, there's the Mandalorian Way (I forget what the specific sect the title character was raised in), which somehow features weapons and armor and has codes of behavior. He actually refers to it as his "religion" while trying to bring his weapons through customs in one episode.

The Guardians of the Whills on Jeddha (Rogue One) probably count as a separate religion from the Jedi.

I remember there were a bunch of others in the old Legends continuity, but I can't bring them to mind except for the brain-in-a-jar monks whose monastery Jabba took over for his palace. I'm not familiar enough with the current canon except for the movies and the live-action shows.

Comment: It was certainly stupid of me to forget the mandalorian religion

Comment: He was part of the children of the watch, which is an offshoot of the nightwatch. The brain in the Jar monks are the B'Omarr Monks if memory serves. There's a story about them in "Tales from Jabba's Palace" in the pre-retcon Legends continuity

Answer (score 0):

As Han says:

> Hokey religion**s** and ancient weapons are no match for a good blaster at your side, kid.

If there was only one religion, it would be very peculiar to refer to it in the plural...