# Why are the Jedi a mystery to the Mandalorians?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In episode 1e08, the Mandalorian meets the armorer again and has this exchange with her:

> Armorer: It looks helpless.
>
> The Mandalorian: It's injured, but it is not helpless. Its species can move objects with its mind.
>
> Armorer: I know of such things. The songs of eons past tell of battles between Mandalore The Great, and an order of sorcerers called Jedi that fought with such powers.

How does this exchange make sense?

The series takes place a few years after the fall of the Empire. So Luke Skywalker should be a well known figure and probably in the process of training new Jedi.

Even if not, the Mandalorians fought in the Clone Wars, where Jedi were still a somewhat common sight. During the the time of the Empire, Darth Vader and Emperor Palapatine were prominent figures with similar powers.

A Mandalorian joined the Jedi order 1000 years ago, why is such an event unknown to the armorer?

Surely, a learned figure in their community like the armorer knows more about Jedi than tales from a war, which happened thousands of years ago.

Comment: This is roughly along the same lines as [Why would the Force become so mysterious and unrecognized after only 20 years?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/20467/4495)

Comment: “So Luke Skywalker should be a well known figure and probably in the process of training new Jedi” — should he? Is there any indication that Luke Skywalker became a well-known figure after the events of Return of the Jedi?

Comment: It's not clear if anyone outside of Han and Leia knows about Luke being a Jedi (or even having Force powers). Most folks in the Rebellion would likely just know him as the hero of Yavin 4 and a X-Wing squadron leader.

Comment: In "The Force Awakens", Rey knows of the legend of Luke and the Force, and she's just a scavenger on a back world planet (at the time). So clearly word got around.

Comment: "A Mandalorian joined the Jedi order 1000 years ago" - is that Disney canon?

Comment: It sounds like they're trying to get back to the feel of the OT, before the prequels told us that every single backstory event happened more or less simultaneously at the hands of one guy, and made the galaxy feel so small. But without officially retconing it.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Disney canon may have forgotten to address it (or maybe they have, I haven't read the novels and such), but in legends, there were literal museum exhibits and such about the Death Stars and Luke's role in the rebellion.

Comment: @NKCampbell Considering Gideon uses the very lightsaber, this Mandalorian who joined the Jedi made, I would think it very strange to cut that event in Disney Canon. Apart from that, I don't think there is a word of how Disney treats old republic stories. Their canon rule mostly applies to stories set around the time of the main Star Wars movies.

Comment: @Dulkan - not arguing anything re: the darksaber. But again, we know next to nothing about this particular clan that Mando is caught up with. Who knows what their knowledge, acceptance of history is. They've already been shown to have what some may call fanatical views re: their helmets, compared to other Mandalorians we've seen in new canon

Comment: @NKCampbell, yes, it's canon. The story was recounted in an episode of "Rebels" that gives the history of the Darksaber.

Comment: I didn't say the darksaber, nor ITs history wasn't canon. But yes re: the 1,000 yr old jedi - thanks. I'm saying @KeithMorrison - that we don't know yet what THIS CLAN of Mandalorians believes or knows. As I said, they have already been shown to have apparently divergent views from other Mandalorians, so who knows what else they differ with. One doesn't have to look too hard in the real world to find groups of people that disagree w/ basic historical truths

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The plausibility of this scenario is that The Mandalorian was just a child when he got adopted and the Jedi were massacred shortly after. And of course the Empire did whatever it could to remove all traces of the Jedi.

And although Luke is a famous figure in the Rebellion this is a vast galaxy and it would take decades for him to become a household name compared to high ranking generals or political leaders like Ackbar or Organa.

Why the Mandaolorians specifically don't know what a Jedi is comes from the point that they rebelled Imperial rule and got massacred. This would leave major gaps in their history.

But you are completely right in the fact that doesn't make any sense at all. Seeing it's suggested (due to her position in the order) she is probably at least a decade older then the main character and therefor should have even witnessed the Clone Wars as a teenager/young adult. And the same goes for some of the other members. So unless there was a form of mass amnesia...

Comment: The rant about Disney is not needed and as shown in the linked question this was the case before Disney acquired SW anyway.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot not a rant, but an observation (Even said that the new additions they made in the Mandalorian were an improvement). There have always been minor retcons but they are a lot more frequent now most notably the removal of a lot of a large chunk of the EU. That makes it a lot more difficult to determine the validity of certain claims.

Comment: More to this, the mandalorians know the legends about the war against the Jedi but probably don't know how they look like and their respective image could've been distorted through the ages. So even if the Armorer saw Jedi Knights fighting in the clone wars, she probably didn't know they were called Jedi/they were the Jedi from the legends, as they are not like anime characters to announce themselves in combat :)

Comment: Even at the height of the Jedi Order they only had 10 thousand or so members in a Galactic Republic that controlled nearly 50 million inhabited systems (with at least as many inhabited systems outside the Republic).  It's not really that hard to believe that someone living at that time might never have heard of Jedi, especially if they're a commoner from a minor world.

Answer (score -1):

Mando was rescued by Deathwatch They clearly knew Jedi and sith at the time of Mandos birth they were fighting mauls rule of Mandalore and Ashoka came to help free them. Then during the siege of Mandalore Kanan and Ezra specifically helped house Wren and house Kryze  defeat Clan Saxon who sides with the empire. the jedi are so deeply entwined with the Mandalorians it is impossible for me to believe they have forgotten the Jedi. The fact that the armorer refers to ancient history to find a legend of jedi confounds me. it is less then 30 years since the jedi were a huge influence on both the republic and Mandalore.

Comment: Is there any evidence that the clan that Mando is seen with in Season 1 is Deathwatch?