# Why do Jedi/Sith play a huge role in shaping the galaxy when the Force doesn't seem that powerful?

Tags: star-wars

> The ability to destroy a planet is insignificant next to the power of the Force -- **Darth Vader**

Force users play an inordinate role in shaping the Galaxy whose history is defined by their actions: The Old Republic was 300 years after the Jedi Civil War and follows a "peace" of sorts due to the domination of the Jedi Order. The marginalization of the Sith was overturned by Palpatine with the destruction of the Jedi Order. The last Jedi, Luke Skywalker, later ended the Galactic Empire.

However, what are the factors which make Force users so special? Canon-wise, Force users appear powerful but not inordinately. For instance, during Order 66 groups of 7 or so droids could down a Jedi -- given how rare Jedi are [as confirmed by this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20467/why-would-the-force-become-so-mysterious-and-unrecognized-after-only-20-years) it would appear that the Jedi Order's total strength could be completely replicated (cheaply) with more droids or clones[image]

Furthermore, highly trained warriors can defeat Force users in a one-on-one fight as is the case with Jango Fett (pictured below).

[image]

Luke's impressive feat of destroying the Death Star was also somewhat replicated by Han Solo and Wedge Antilles, implying that while the Force confers a valuable edge, it does not appear to be an insurmountable one.

Comment: We see a group of 7 droids taking out a lone Jedi, but we also see a lone Jedi taking out entire ships full of clones.

Comment: That looks more like Jango sniping an otherwise occupied Jedi than a one-on-one fight.

Comment: "A valuable edge". . . Being able to win 51% of all games you play ensures you'll eventually rise to the top, right?

Comment: Darth Nihilus could destroy a planet using the Force.

Comment: “during Order 66 groups of 7 or so droids could down a Jedi” — sure, but Order 66 is a unique case. There’s a galaxy-wide army made up of trained clones, who the Jedi have been fighting alongside for years, who all simultaneously turn on them. That’s incredibly hard to defend against, and inconceivably hard for anyone else to replicate. When the Jedi know you’re coming and have time to prepare, they tend to win, or at least survive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The influence of the Jedi and Sith is not from combat power.

As Mace Windu states, the Jedi are peacekeepers, not soldiers.

In Episode 1, there was a planet wide blockade of a planet by a huge army and space fleet. The Jedi order sent two Jedi, confident that this would end the conflict. If it weren't for the Sith influence, it seems probable that this would have ended the blockade almost immediately as the Trade Federation 'dare not go against the Jedi'.

The Jedi's influence comes from their wisdom, respected role, history, traditions and impartiality, not from their fighting prowess.

Similarly, the Sith's influence comes from political power, espionage and manipulation. Looking through the movies, you see few instances of sith in combat with non-Jedi, so the movies would run almost the same regardless of their fighting skills.

The main force powers that help the Jedi and Sith achieve their objectives are mind control and being able to see the future, not the combat powers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any book or media references, but it seems that whatever side of the Force is more prevalent influences the galaxy as a whole towards the ideals of that side of the Force. When the dark side is in power: empires rise, and people lose their freedoms and become controlled by those with the power. When the light side is in power: democracy takes charge and people are given freedom to choose their own paths. The Republic was formed right after the dark side was defeated, and lasted until the dark side got strong enough again to corrupt the Republic and eventually even overthrow it to become an Empire. So, while the individuals themselves might not be overarchingly powerful, the influence that they protect is.